# How to create UpdateView Form that include both main model and its ForeignKey in same html?

Tags: django, django-forms, django-views

I have a model that i would like to include Update using UpdateView form using Main model and its related ForeignKey , so desired resault would include both main model object and all its related ForeignKey objects

My model and view shown below as follows

Please advice

Thanks

Model

```
class MainTask(models.Model):
    task_title = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    global_task_info = models.TextField(max_length=500,default=None) 
    complete = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    overall_precent_complete = models.PositiveIntegerField(default=0)
    created_at = models.DateTimeField(default=datetime.datetime.now())
    updated_at = models.DateTimeField(default=datetime.datetime.now())
    due_date = models.DateTimeField(default=datetime.datetime.now())
    task_location = models.CharField(max_length=400, blank=True, null=True)

    global_task_assign = models.ForeignKey(UserProfile, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name="global_task_assign",default=1)
    TASK_STATUS_CHOICES = [
    ('ST', 'STARTED'),
    ('NS', 'NOT STARTED'),
    ('IP', 'IN PROGRESS'),
    ('PA', 'PAUSED'),
    ('CO', 'COMPLETED'),
    ]
    task_status = models.CharField(max_length=2,choices=TASK_STATUS_CHOICES,default='NOT STARTED')

    def __str__(self):
        return self.task_title



class ChildTask(models.Model):
    # Relationship Fields
    item_main = models.ForeignKey('MainTask',on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name="item_main", )
    task_description = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    task_info = models.TextField(blank = True)
    task_complete = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    sub_task = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    task_precent_complete = models.PositiveIntegerField(default=0)
    task_created = models.DateTimeField(default=datetime.datetime.now())
    task_updated_at = models.DateTimeField(default=datetime.datetime.now())
    task_due_date = models.DateTimeField(default=datetime.datetime.now())


    task_assign = models.ForeignKey(UserProfile, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name="task_assign",default=1)


    def __str__(self):
        return self.task_description
```

View

```
class TaskIdUpdateView(UpdateView):
model = MainTask
template_name = "taskid_update.html"
form_class = TaskUpdateForm
fields = '__all__'
```

Comment: you want to add user profile to this view programmatically?

Comment: No , only the user name to assign in the form

Comment: post your profile model also

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take a look at the django documentation for [django inline formset](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/topics/forms/modelforms/#inline-formsets).

Answer (score 0):

You can add a form valid method to your update view as follows, and assign user from user profile

```
def form_valid(self, form):
    global_task_assign = UserProfile.objects.get(user=self.request.user)
    form.instance.global_task_assign = global_task_assign
    valid_data = super(TaskIdUpdateView, self).form_valid(form)
    return valid_data
```